# How can I insert my own demosaicing algorithm into rawtherapee or darktable's pipeline?

Tags: software, demosaicing

If I give Rawtherapee or Darktable a raw image, they will automatically transform the raw image using their internal pipeline to an output image.

Let's say I have designed a new demosaicing algorithm and I want to use it in the pipeline. I know that I can apply everything on a raw image in the pipeline just before the demosaicing; let's say I demosaic the image with my method. Is there some way in Rawtherapee or Darktable to apply the rest of the pipeline on the demosaiced image ?

Comment: Do you realize without demosaicing you will have a monochrome image? And one that will have varying luminance values from one pixel to the next based on the color of the light that fell on the sensor covered by a Bayer filter?

Comment: Thanks for your note; I changed my explanation to make my point more clear

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39935/effect-of-each-step-in-raw-image-pipleline

Comment: Rawtherapee already supports multiple demosaicing algorithms. Have you considered adding yours as another option (even if only in your own local build)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be the easiest way to go; thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RawTherapee and darktable are both open source projects - that means you can modify the software to use your own demosaicing algorithm.

I'm not familiar with the source code of those projects so I don't know how easy or difficult it is to change the demosaicing algorithm - but my guess is its easier than writing a substantially better demosaicing algorithm.

BTW, the demosaicing is pretty early in the pipeline, most meaningful image processing algorithms can't work on the raw data without seriously messing up the image colors, running only the pre-demosaicing part of the pipeline is unlikely to be useful.